# Why Polymer doesn't read behavior properties?

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, web-component

I've created a Behavior like:

```
 var MB = MB || {}; //set Marvin Behaviors namespace

    MB.translate = {
        properties: {
            key: {
                type: String,
                value: 'Foo',
                notify: true
            }
        },
        someMethod: function(){
            console.log(this.key);
        }...
```

When I mixin this behavior in other  components i get `undefined` logged to console.
The only way to solve it is to reference full path like `console.log(MB.translate.properties.key.value);` in original method, which seems as not the right way. What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that works; `key` in that context is `undefined` as expected — unless you define it further in the prototype.

You should use `console.log(this.properties.key);`.

**NOTE**: I know nothing about Polymer, but my understanding is that this is specific to ECMAScript and hence to Polymer. I may be wrong, feel free to "flag" me and correct this.

Comment: This is a feature of Polymer: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html

Comment: @AlexNasonov Agreed, but that's an object member and you are referring to it out of its scope; that was my point

Comment: Just tried to make it this way: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html

Comment: I think the piece you are missing here is that these behaviors are copied into polymer elements so when the method itself is called the context (this) is the polymer element itself.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `this` refers to the function, not the whole object literal. To solve it you must reference the whole path like you did, or you create a bound function, but you cannot do this in the Object literal definition, only afterwards:

```js
var MB = MB || {}; //set Marvin Behaviors namespace

MB.translate = {
  properties: {
    key: {
      type: String,
      value: 'Foo',
      notify: true
    }
  }
}

MB.translate.someMethod = function() {
  console.log(this.key);
}.bind(MB.translate.properties)

MB.translate.someMethod();
```

Edit: sorry I wasnt completely right: the correct answer is that `this` refers to the scope of the parent. So you could also do this, which I guess is more what you want:

```
someMethod: function(){
    console.log(this.properties.key);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work like this and it's different comparing to example given on Polymer website. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html

Comment: Both methods I outlined work, and this has nothing to do with Polymer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reference the fully qualified object when mixing in the behavior?

I think your namespace should be attached to the window object:

```
window.MB = window.MB || {};
MB.translate = { ... }
```

Then you can mixin like this:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    behaviors: [MB.translate]
  });
</script>
```